# Disabling command button: Can't locate commandbutton through VBA; Runtime Error 9

Tags: database, vba

I'm trying to disable a command button which copies a line of data and parses in into another sheet. That part works, and I've tried the following code in an separate worksheet and everything works. When I put the code into the VBA for the excel database I get created I receive an error: "Run Time error 9: subscript out of range"
I figure I'm not putting in the address to the file properly. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Last_row As Long
Last_row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Worksheets("NewQuotes").Range("AM" & Last_row).Value <= Now() Then               
Worksheets("NewQuotes").CommandButton2.Enabled = False                           
Worksheets("S:\PRICE LISTS 1\[Sales Database.xlsm]NewQuotes").Shapes("CommandButton2").ControlFormat.Enabled = False  
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? and what do you mean by "When I try the code in my database"?

Comment: What database are you referring to? Access?

Comment: I created excel database on first the work sheet (Sales Database.xlsm); work sheet 2, 3 & 4 are the sheets to have information parsed onto.

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: error in: If Worksheets("NewQuotes").Range("AM" & Last_row).Value <= Now() Then               'deem expiry of last line

Comment: That means there is a problem with value of `Last_row` (what value is it?) or the contents of that cell. You do have a worksheet named "NewQuotes" don't you?

Comment: Of course I do :P I just realized the Last_row function definition got deleted. I added it back and now I get error -2147024809 (80070057) "the item with the specified name wasn't found" on line :    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NewQuotes").Shapes("Commandbutton2").ControlFormat.Enabled = False

Comment: I'm not sure you need that line of code. If you've got a CommandButton then `Worksheets("NewQuotes").CommandButton2.Enabled = False ` should suffice.

Comment: well that line doesn't cause an error and works in my other workbook but on this one nothing happens. The second line grays out the button

Answer (score 0):

To reference a command button use the following syntax:

If both the code and command button (named CommandButton2) are in same workbook:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet_name").CommandButton2.Enabled = False
```

If they are in different books:

```
Workbooks("book_name.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet_name").CommandButton2.Enabled = False
```

Comment: Ooops. No but it only needs to match the name that has been given to the control. Will fix.